# Где правильнее обрабытывать события в DialogFragment?

Tags: android, dialogfragment

У меня есть `DialogFragment` в котором я могу обработать события двумя способами:

1. произвести обработку в активити из которого он был вызван:

   ```
   ((MainActivity) getActivity()).okClicked();
   ```
2. произвести обработку непосредственно в `DialogFragment`.

Как сделать правильно?

Comment: Там, где посчитаете нужным. Без контекста задачи сказать однозначно - невозможно

Comment: какого рода событие? требуется ли для его выполнения окружение активити? Вопрос слишком общий, чтобы дать полезный ответ. Правильными будут оба способа в зависимости от решаемой задачи.